# Increase left and right height in AVL Tree Implementation

Tags: java, avl-tree

So I'm trying to write a RR Rotation and LL Rotation with Java for an AVL tree. I have most of it figured out, however I don't know where I should modify the height within the method. I've been trying to understand it for a few days here but I cannot figure out where exactly it would go in the method I currently have. If someone could help explain exactly where I should put the modifications for the height of the node (it uses getLeft/setLeft for it's left height and getRight/setRight for it's right height) it would be extremely helpful!

```
/**
 * Performs a right shift of the current critical node. (Left rotation)
 * @precond Tree is not empty.
 * @return a tree with the updated rotation.
 **/ 
public BinaryNodeAVL280<I> shiftLeftRotation(BinaryNodeAVL280<I> critNode)
{

    if(this.rootNode() == null)
    {
        throw new ContainerEmpty280Exception("Cannot rotate an empty AVL tree!");
    }

    //TempNode becomes right of A (which is C)
    BinaryNodeAVL280<I> tempNode = (BinaryNodeAVL280<I>) critNode.rightNode();
    //Set the parent of tempNode (A) to be critNode's parent.
    tempNode.setParent(critNode.getParent());

    //Set critNode (A)'s left Node (which is B) to tempNode's leftNode (C's left which is D)
    critNode.setRightNode(tempNode.leftNode());

    //Check if the rightNode of A is null.
    if(critNode.rightNode() != null)
    {
        //If not null, set A's right parent (C's parent) to current parent.
        ((BinaryNodeAVL280<I>) critNode.rightNode()).setParent(critNode);
    }

    //Set Left node of C (was D) to critNode (A)
    tempNode.setLeftNode(critNode);

    //Set critNode's (unknown for now) to temp node (C).
    critNode.setParent(tempNode);

    //If parent of C is not null.
    if(tempNode.getParent() != null)
    {
        //If the right child of tempNode is the same as critNode
        if(tempNode.getParent().rightNode() == critNode)
            //Set the right child to tempNode.
            tempNode.getParent().setRightNode(tempNode);
        //If the child of temp node's left side is equal to critNode
        else if(tempNode.getParent().leftNode() == critNode)
            //Set temp node's left to tempNode(b)
            tempNode.getParent().setLeftNode(tempNode);
    }

    //increment height somehow...

    return tempNode;
}
```

Comment: couldn't you just recalculate the height after you're done with the rotation, starting from the root?

Comment: I do believe I could do that, but this whole AVL Tree also has to have a time complexity of O(logn), so wouldn't that make it O(nlogn)?

Comment: otherwise if you know that the rotation will only change the height to +-1 you can use that fact...

Comment: I know I can, it's just I'm having troubles as to where I should put it. I'm trying to comprehend where the height increase should go within my method here.

Comment: In theory, the caller of the method might know which way the height is supposed to be adjusted. But in principle, once your tempNode replaces your critNode, tempNode.right is unchanged, and tempNode.left is what critNode was. So if you know the height of critNode you can figure out the change of height: height(tempNode) = 1+max(height(<new critNode>), height(tempNode.right)) = 1+max(1+max(height(critNode.left), height(tempNode.left)), height(tempNode.right)) (and so on...) But if you know that you call this method to reduce the height, then the resulting tree should be 1 less :)